# Avoid Credential in Apex REST Callout Code

Tags: apex, integration, security, apexrest, authentication

In my current implementation of an Apex REST callout code to external system , I have to set an endpoint using a Named credentials-`NAMED_CRED`. The Named 
Credential has an endpoint like -

```
https://xyz.com/res/login?userID=XXX&password=YYYY
```

I use `req.setEndpoint('callout:NAMED_CRED')` in my code while making a Callout. This approach is showing up in security analysis that it is not safe
to send the userid and password in URL. Is there any other way I can set the credential details with out hardcoding the credentials in the COde.
One of the good practice I want to follow is not to change the code when credential detail changes or endpoint has to be changed. Is there way to do this?

The code using POST:

```
public class jsonWrapper {
        public String userID {get; set;}
        public String Password {get; set;}
}

jsonWrapper wrap = new jsonWrapper();
wrap.userID = 'YYYY';
wrap.Password = 'xxx';
String jsonBody = json.serialize(wrap);
system.debug('JSON Body****' + jsonBody);

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
HTTP auth = new HTTP();
HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
r.setClientCertificateName('CERT');
r.setEndpoint('https://xyz.com/login');
r.setMethod('POST');   
r.setBody(jsonBody);     

HTTPResponse authresp=new HttpResponse();
authresp = auth.send(r); 
System.debug(authresp.getBody());
system.debug(authresp);
```

Output I get :

```
17:18:04:002 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|JSON Body****{"userID":"SA-ITS-SFDCRESTUser","Password":"Ez4u2Get"}
17:18:05:446 USER_DEBUG [22]|DEBUG|{"statusCode":"1160","severity":"FATAL","statusMessage":"Required String parameter 'userID' is not present"}
17:18:05:446 USER_DEBUG [23]|DEBUG|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the credentials in the query string isn't safe. Any system that can see the request coming through can read the values straight of the request. Rather, switch to a POST request and encrypt them in the body of the message.

Better yet, switch to one of the [Authentication Protocols](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_authentication_providers.htm&type=0&language=en_US) supported by named credentials. Rolling your own authentication is always a recipe for a security problem.

Comment: Thanks , Can you show me an example how to do a POST request and encrypt them in the body of the message? I do not want to hardcode anything.

Comment: I don't believe you can do a POST request with authentication details stored in a Named Credential. You could need to use another method to store the credentials, such as protected custom settings in a managed package.

Comment: Can you give me the syntax on how I can add the credential in the body of the message. Is this the correct way - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm

Comment: The basic Authorization header shown in that post is certainly one option. What does the web service you are calling support? There is also a GET example if [Securing Your Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_crypto.htm?search_text=HttpRequest). To put the details in the POST body would require using `setBody` on the HttpRequest. Try to avoid rolling your own authentication.

Comment: Can you see my edit. I am trying to POST and adding the credential in the body using setBody(). Does this look correct. Why does this error occurs -  {"statusCode":"1160","severity":"FATAL","statusMessage":"Required String parameter 'userID' is not present"} . Any idea?

Comment: @SfdcBat - I believe You are at the mercy of the external system and what it can support. If it is looking for a query parameter and it chokes when not present I am not sure you can pass it any other way. I am probably wrong though...Good read on the security around this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure

Comment: @Eric I am in mercy of external system :) Am I doing the callout correctly? In terms of passing the credentials in body of POST method? Thanks

Comment: @SfdcBat - It all depends on what the external system can accept. If JSON then I guess, if form then it would be like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request - "Correct" is defined by the external system which hopefully follows some standard

Comment: @Eric the external system can accept JSOn. What I meant was am I forming my request body appropriately using json.serialize method and using a apex class to form the JSON

Comment: @SfdcBat - From a quick glance yes, except you are not setting the content type to `application/json`